# How to load datapoints from array in CanvasJS to make a chart?

Tags: javascript, canvasjs

i want to make a chart with data from an array. But couldn't figure out why isn't any data showing up in my chart.
Can you guys help me to solve this problem?

```
   
   var dataset = [];
   
   
   
   $(data.items).each(function (index, item) 
   {

dataset.push(item.SQA);
   });
   

   console.log("5. item: " + dataset[5]);
   console.log("array items: " + dataset);
   
   var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("wrapper_dia", {
   animationEnabled: true,
   theme: "light2",
   title:{
       text: "Simple Line Chart"
   },
   data: [{        
       type: "line",
       indexLabelFontSize: 16,
       dataPoints: dataset
       
   }]
   
   
});
chart.render();
```

[image: Here is the picutre of the console.log with the data that i want to put on the line chart:]

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through the array and parsing it to the format accepted by CanvasJS before passing to the chart options. Check the below code snippet for the same.

```
var dps = [];    
function parseDataPoints () {
    for (var i = 0; i <= dataArray.length; i++)
      dps.push({y: dataArray[i]});     
};
    
parseDataPoints();
chart.options.data[0].dataPoints = dps;
chart.render();
```

Check out this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/canvasjs/zxbtLq27/) for an example on the same.